# XPath returns wrong element

Tags: java, xpath, cucumber, gherkin

I have a problem with XPath returning wrong element in code, but working as intended when I put it in my browser and search element with such xpath.

The path that the code executes returns the div of the next xpath.

For example xpath:

```
//div [@class="product justify-content-md-center"][1]/h2
```

returns the 2nd element instead of the 1st as it should, but when I paste it in the browser it gets the correct element, so I think it's not an xpath problem. I am using serenity cucumber automation with java.

I am trying to get elements from my project site that has a catalog with 12 div products. Here is the html with the php code listing the 12 products:

```
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         extract($row);
         echo "<div class='product justify-content-md-center'>";
         echo "<img class='beerPicture' src='beers/{$picture}' style='height: 130px; width:130px'>";
         echo "<div class='click-callback'></div>";
         echo "<h2 class='header my-3 text-truncate'>{$name}</h2>";
         echo "<p class='description' style='display: none;'>{$description}</p>";
         echo "<p class='price'>{$price} lv.</p>";

         if ($quantity == 0) {
             echo "<h2 class='text_shadow'>Out of Stock</h2>";
         } else {
             $cartId = $row["id"];
             echo "<a class='btn' href='cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=$cartId'>Add to cart</a>";
         }
             echo "<div class='quickview'>Description</div>";
             echo "</div>";
         }
    }
}
```

My method for getting the xpath of each individual div:

```
public String getProductName(int product) {
     String productName = getProduct().getWrappedElement().toString();
     String toRemove = productName.substring(0, 78);
     String result   = productName.replace(toRemove, "").replace("]/h2[text()]", "");

     String targetProductName = 
         result + "[" + product + "]" 
       + "/h2[@class=\"header my-3 text-truncate\" and text()]";

     System.out.println(targetProductName);
     System.out.println(getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(targetProductName)).getAttribute("textContent"));

     return getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(targetProductName)).getAttribute("textContent");
  }
```

And my gherkin scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: I should be able to view description of any product
    Given I am logged in and on catalog page
    When I click on <any> product description button
    Then I should be shown the <any> product description
    Examples:
      |any|
      |1  |
      |2  |
      |3  |
      |4  |
      |5  |
      |6  |
      |7  |
      |8  |
      |9  |
      |10 |
      |11 |
      |12 |
```

Comment: Tried to add a sample of plain html with 3 simplified div so xpath your can be tested.